# Convert multiple Excel sheets into separate csv files

Tags: excel, csv, command-line, terminal, type-conversion

Now I used the `xslx2csv` tool which I saw in other answers of similar questions on stackoverflow and run the code: `xlsx2csv --all file.xlsx` in my terminal. But all that does is print all the sheets of the `xlsx` file as a `csv` in my terminal instead of creating separate `csv` files in for each sheet my current directory.

This should be simple but I can't find simple answers..

How do I solve this? All help much appreciated!

Comment: I think it's working properly, it's just not designed to split them all into separate files. Is [this](http://cwestblog.com/2011/05/05/excel-batch-convert-xls-to-csv/) helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Since you [seem to be using R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53883593/2114932), here is an R-based solution. You need the {readxl}, {purrr}, and {readr} packages. I am “namespacing” all functions, so you know, where they are from.
I am using the example Excel file from {readxl}.

```r
path_to_xlsx <- readxl::readxl_example("datasets.xlsx")
```

This Excel file has 4 sheets. The names of the sheets are read by `excel_sheets`.

```r
sheet_names <- readxl::excel_sheets(path_to_xlsx)
```

Now we import all excel sheets into one list.

```r
sheets <- purrr::map(sheet_names, ~ readxl::read_excel(path_to_xlsx, sheet = .x))
```

We get a list of 4 data.frames or tibbles. Let’s name them.

```r
base::names(sheets) <- sheet_names
```

Now export all tibbles from the list to separate CSVs in one go.

```r
purrr::iwalk(sheets, ~ readr::write_excel_csv2(x = .x, path = paste0(.y, ".csv")))

list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")
#> [1] "chickwts.csv" "iris.csv"     "mtcars.csv"   "quakes.csv"
```