# Export csv with ISO-8859-1 encoding instead of UTF-8

Tags: r, character-encoding, stringr

I struggle with encoding in csv exports. I'm from the Netherlands and we use quite some trema's (e.g. `ë`, `ï`) and accents (e.g. `é`, `ó`) etc. This causes troubles when exporting to csv and open file in excel.

On macOS Mojave.

I've tried multiple encoding functions like the following.

```
library(stringr)
library(readr)

test <- c("Argentinië", "België", "Haïti")

test %>%
  stringi::stri_conv(., "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1") %>%
  write.csv2("~/Downloads/test.csv")
```

But still, this causes weird characters:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not on the Excel end?  As a control, can you try opening the CSV file in something like Notepad++, to see if the encoding looks correct there?

Comment: Yes in a normal text editor it goes without problems. So it probably is an excel problem... How do I take care of people importing the right encoding in their Excel..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I take care of people importing the right encoding in their Excel..?

Don’t convert to iso-8859-1 but export with `readr::write_excel_csv2()`. It writes the file as UTF-8, but with [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which Excel understands).

```r
library(readr)
test <- c("Argentinië", "België", "Haïti")
```

I need to convert `test` to UTF-8, because I am on Windows.

```r
test <- enc2utf8(test)
```

On MacOS `test` should be in UTF-8 already, as that is the native encoding.

```r
Encoding(test)
#> [1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8" "UTF-8"
```

Save as an Excel csv with `readr::write_excel_csv2()`

```r
write_excel_csv2(data.frame(x = test), "test.csv")
```

Alternatively save as `xlsx` with `writexl::write_xlsx()`

```r
writexl::write_xlsx(data.frame(x = test), "test.xlsx")
```

[image: test.csv in Excel]

Answer (score 0):

`test <- c("Argentinië", "België", "Haïti")`

`con <- file('~/test.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")`

`write.csv(x = test, file = con)`

A call to `csvlook test.csv -e "ISO-8859-1"` in my bash
returns 

`| a | x          |
| - | ---------- |
| 1 | Argentinië |
| 2 | België     |
| 3 | Haïti      |`

Comment: Hmmm yes I think the trouble starts when opening in Excel...If I open the file in a text editor all goes well...

Comment: This is likely an Excel issue.

Comment: I see, I am on a Mac, I tested with Numbers as well and it works fine.

Comment: So I can't do nothing in `R` which solves the problem?

Comment: at least in the past, Excel came with an import wizard for csv files where you could specify the encoding ...

Comment: Yes it still does, but that's hard to explain to other people using the csv files in excel... But it might be the only way. Or just build spreadsheets with `library(googlesheets)`

Comment: I see ... I have been there and my solution was to attach a couple of png files with as a step by step tutorial ...

Answer (score 0):

do the simple thing

Just open the file in note pad and save as UTF -8 in another name, now open the saved notepad file in excel and it will ask you import, do delimiter based on your report and use , also as delimiter for columns separation and finish import. you will get your clean file